# how to restore the backup of windows installation disk image

Tags: windows-7, boot, disk-image

I had low disk space problem in windows 7 installation. And there was no way to increase the volume size of my C: drive. So I first backup the disks unix `cat` command.

```
cat /dev/sdb1 > /media/tape8/sdb1_windows7.img
```

Then I repartitioned my hard disk. Give enough space (30GB) to windows drive (C:). After that I restore the image to the new 30GB partition by

```
cat /media/tape8/sdb1_windows7.img > /dev/sdb1
```

Now I try to boot windows. It doesn't boot. I try to repair by windows 7 installation disk. Tried Startup Repair, nothing changes.

My question is, on this scenario how do I boot my existing windows?

Comment: That is quite an unusual way to back up a disk - dd might have worked better, or to use some bootable disk repartitioning tool.

Comment: Yeah, DD was better. But dd is way too slow. and selecting optimal bsize is the key here. But I could find the proper size. I did the cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would try:

Shrink the partition back to original size (i hope you backed up your partition table) and put the data back. Hopefully this will boot. In Windows and use `diskmgmt.msc` to extend the volume to the free space ...